# Path to value in .JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

JSON accesed from my API on local network:

```
http://localhost:3005/products?q=lc
```

and it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "774944",
        "general": {
            "presentable_id": "774944",
            "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå",
            "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan.</b></p><p>Denne Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i cyan har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Cyan</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
        },
        "brand": {
            "name": "Brother Norge AS"
        },
        "images": {
            "primary": {
                "large": "https://i.imgur.com/zYcibjw.jpg"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "774945",
        "general": {
            "presentable_id": "774945",
            "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLM rød",
            "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta.</b></p><p>Denne Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i magenta har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Magenta</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
        },
        "brand": {
            "name": "Brother Norge AS"
        },
        "images": {
            "primary": {
                "large": "https://i.imgur.com/ucfnti1.jpg"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "774946",
        "general": {
            "presentable_id": "774946",
            "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLY gul",
            "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med den gule Brother LC1280XLY-blekkpatronen.</b></p><p>Denne gule Brother LC1280XLY-blekkpatronen med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne gule blekkpatronen har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Gul</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
        },
        "brand": {
            "name": "Brother Norge AS"
        },
        "images": {
            "primary": {
                "large": "https://i.imgur.com/6zdrajU.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I wish to get all 'id' item's value as an array, I have tried this:

```
console.log(products[0].id)
console.log('products?q=lc'[0].id)
console.log(products?q=lc[0].id)
console.log(this[0].id)
```

but returns only undefined. Any hint would be very appreciated here.
How to get items value and use it as an array?

Comment: You don't show *how* you call this API nor how you store the results. It may be an issue with asynchronous calls, it may be an issue with not getting the "data" from the response. You need to show more code.

Comment: I have no idea how you think options 2-4 you tried were going to work? We're missing how you store the result in what variable before you can access it.

Comment: you have to map it and get all ids

Comment: KIndly share your api and how you are storing the result. My guess would be same as crashmstr that you are not storing the value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const products = [
{
"id": "774944",
"general": {
  "presentable_id": "774944",
  "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå",
  "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan.</b></p><p>Denne Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i cyan har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Cyan</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
},
"brand": {
  "name": "Brother Norge AS"
},
"images": {
  "primary": {
    "large": "https://i.imgur.com/zYcibjw.jpg"
  }
}
},
{
"id": "774945",
"general": {
  "presentable_id": "774945",
  "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLM rød",
  "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta.</b></p><p>Denne Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i magenta har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Magenta</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
},
"brand": {
  "name": "Brother Norge AS"
},
"images": {
  "primary": {
    "large": "https://i.imgur.com/ucfnti1.jpg"
  }
}
},
{
"id": "774946",
"general": {
  "presentable_id": "774946",
  "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLY gul",
  "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med den gule Brother LC1280XLY-blekkpatronen.</b></p><p>Denne gule Brother LC1280XLY-blekkpatronen med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne gule blekkpatronen har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Gul</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
},
"brand": {
  "name": "Brother Norge AS"
},
"images": {
  "primary": {
    "large": "https://i.imgur.com/6zdrajU.jpg"
  }
}
},
]
const ids = products.map(product => product.id)
console.log(ids)
```

So `map` does the trick.

You can find more about awesome array functions here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp

Answer (score 0):

After you parse your response with `const data = JSOM.parse(response)`
you can `map` an new array with the ids only:

```js
var data= [
    {
        "id": "774944",
        "general": {
            "presentable_id": "774944",
            "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLC blå",
            "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan.</b></p><p>Denne Brother LC1280XLC-blekkpatronen i cyan med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i cyan har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Cyan</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
        },
        "brand": {
            "name": "Brother Norge AS"
        },
        "images": {
            "primary": {
                "large": "https://i.imgur.com/zYcibjw.jpg"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "774945",
        "general": {
            "presentable_id": "774945",
            "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLM rød",
            "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta.</b></p><p>Denne Brother LC1280XLM-blekkpatronen i magenta med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne blekkpatronen i magenta har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Magenta</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
        },
        "brand": {
            "name": "Brother Norge AS"
        },
        "images": {
            "primary": {
                "large": "https://i.imgur.com/ucfnti1.jpg"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "774946",
        "general": {
            "presentable_id": "774946",
            "name": "Blekk BROTHER LC1280XLY gul",
            "description": "<p><b>Få optimale utskriftsresultater, tydelig tekst og levende grafikk med den gule Brother LC1280XLY-blekkpatronen.</b></p><p>Denne gule Brother LC1280XLY-blekkpatronen med stor kapasitet produserer levende, stilige resultater i utskrifter av høy kvalitet. Blekket er laget for optimal bruk med ulike Brother-maskiner og har flekkbestandig blekk som ikke falmer, for svært holdbare utskrifter. Denne gule blekkpatronen har en kapasitet på opptil 1200 sider.</p><li>Farge: Gul</li><li>Kapasitet: Opptil 1200 A4-sider </li><li>Enkel å installere og skifte ut</li><li>Flekkbestandig og falmer ikke</li><li>Gir tekst og bilder med utmerket kvalitet</li><li>Se kompatibilitetsoversikten for passende maskiner</li>"
        },
        "brand": {
            "name": "Brother Norge AS"
        },
        "images": {
            "primary": {
                "large": "https://i.imgur.com/6zdrajU.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
];

const ids = data.map(item => item.id);
console.log(ids)
```